# Inconsistent handling of UI calls from non-UI thread for TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, tabcontrol

This is not a duplicate. This particular behavior of a WinForms TabControl has not been explored on StackOverflow.

Check out the example below:

I have a **TabControl** in .NET 4.0 with two tabs. Each tab has a **Label** placed within it. When I click the **Button**, I launch a **BackgroundWorker** which is now operating on a non-UI thread. If I try to change the **Label** from tabPage1, I get an **InvalidOperationException** because of the cross-thread call. But that second line which modifies the **Label** on tabPage2 runs perfectly fine - no exceptions.

[image: Simple test form to demonstrate the problem]

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.DoWork += Bgw_DoWork;
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        label1.Text = "Testing tabPage1"; // This is sitting on tabPage1 - THROWS CROSS THREAD OPERATION
        label2.Text = "Testing tabPage2"; // This is sitting on tabPage2 - RUNS FINE
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Why is this allowed on tabPage2 but disallowed on tabPage1. In both instances, we are seemingly modifying the UI from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it works when it shouldn't.  But, "don't do that" anyway - it will fail when you really don't want it to.

Comment: Is there any explanation as to why this works but shouldn't? I am sure someone knows.

Comment: Does the code actually look like this? Because if you get an exception on the first line, the second line won't even execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a) the setter of the `Control.Text` property:

```
set
{
    // some code omitted

    this.WindowText = value;
    this.OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);

    // some code omitted
}
```

It just forwards to the `Control.WindowText` property. Let's inspect that one:

```
set 
{
    if (value == null) value = "";
    if (!WindowText.Equals(value)) {
        if (IsHandleCreated) {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowText(new HandleRef(window, Handle), value);
        }
        else {
            if (value.Length == 0) {
                text = null;
            }
            else {
                text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `InvalidOperationException` originates from the `Handle` property getter, which is called to obtain a `HandleRef` instance for the native method call.

```
get {
    if (checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls &&
        !inCrossThreadSafeCall &&
        InvokeRequired) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.IllegalCrossThreadCall, Name));
    }

    // further code omitted
}
```

The `Handle` property will be only accessed when `IsHandleCreated` is `true`. In your case, the second label is located on a tab item whose children are not displayed yet, so `IsHandleCreated` for the second label is `false`. That means, the `Handle` property of the second label is not accessed on the `BackgroundWorker`'s thread. Instead, the text value is just cached in a `text` field inside the control. Therefore - no exception.

When you activate the second tab item, the `Label`'s handle is created, and the .NET Framework code takes the cached text value from the `text` field and applies it to the label. This occurs on the UI thread, so again - no exceptions there.

You can **first** switch to the second tab item and **then** press your button. You will observe the exception. That is because the handle for the second label will be already created in this case.

As a general note - you should **never** access the UI elements from worker threads, regardless whether you observe those exceptions or not. For **all** interaction with the UI elements from other threads, use synchronization: `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`, `SynchronizationContext`, `TaskScheduler` etc.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. But I would disagree with your final paragraph. It is perfectly acceptable to work on UI elements from a worker thread so long as the Handle is not created. For example, while loading an application. You may have a splash screen to show time-intensive loading and during that time you touch the UI so long as the UI elements have no Handle. You can create the Control, work on it, and then save the final step of adding the Control to your form to be performed from the UI thread.

Comment: @MichaelMankus, it is not acceptable to access UI elements from worker threads because of possible race conditions and other issues that might be caused by not synchronized read&write resource access by different threads.